# Chunk size confusion regarding wav files

Tags: c, wav, dataformat

I am trying to parse a .wav file using c file handling. I have a small confusion regarding the output I am getting. given below is the code I am running to parse the .wav file currently I am just parsing the header portion of the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{

    char* ChunkId;
    char* fmt;
    u_int32_t ChunkSize;

}Header;

int main(void){

    FILE * file = fopen("piano2.wav","r");

    Header header; 
    header.ChunkId = malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);
    header.fmt = malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);

    if(file == NULL){
        return 1;
    }

    fread(header.ChunkId,sizeof(char),4,file);
    fread(&header.ChunkSize,sizeof(u_int32_t),1,file);
    fread(header.fmt,sizeof(char),4,file);


    printf("%s\n",header.ChunkId);
    printf("%u\n",header.ChunkSize);
    printf("%s\n",header.fmt);

    fclose(file);
    free(header.ChunkId);
    free(header.fmt);
}
```

I am getting this output after running the code.

```
RIFF
1210884
WAVE
```

The RIFF and WAVE part of the output is clear to me, but the 2nd line is where I am having a small problem understanding. How much is the chunk size actually? I am having a hard time calculating it, I know it's a 32 bit number in little-endian form, I have the output in unsigned int form. Should I convert it into hex? and then convert into big-endian and then calculate the chunk size, or is the output itself the chunk size ?

Comment: That's the file size in bytes. Is it not roughly the same as the input `piano2.wav` size?

Comment: Ok, assuming it's the no of bytes, when I convert it to Mb I get 1.21 Mb but the file size is 1.15 Mb. It's close but it's showing more than the file size it self.

Comment: `1210884` is not 1.21 MB. It's `1210884 / (1024 * 1024) == 1.15 MB`

Comment: Lol I'm a noob, I divided by 1000 * 1000, forgot it's 1024. Anyways thanks, well rather be a noob and get wrecked and learn from it instead of never really asking the question.

Comment: You need 1024 bytes in kilobytes and 1024 kb for a megabyte. I think we all made that mistake at some point of our life, no worries!

Comment: Aside: I would explicitly pass the data type to `fopen()`, that is `"rb"` to ensure the code is portable (does not confuse line endings).